# Winston not logging at any log level, what could be wrong?

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I have run in to a weird bug and don't know how to proceed/debug. I have an app that's written in Nodejs and uses Winston for logging. Everything was working fine until I brought up a new production server yesterday and retired the old one.

My prod server has 4 Nodejs processes running. On the new production server, Winston logs the very first log message per .js file, period. It stops logging after that, and changing the log level doesn't work. My app has got about 6 .js files, and in case of any error on any of those files, the very first error message gets logged but any subsequent errors/warning/info are not logged.

The funny thing is Winston was working just fine on the old prod server and the dev server still works fine.

I am on Winston 0.6.2 on both dev and prod. As far as I know, all the sw packages are the same between dev and prod.

How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I came across this issue => https://github.com/flatiron/winston/issues/227

Looks like, the new way of handling streams in the latest version of node has broken file transport in winston. I am going back to node v0.8.22 for the time being as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

What transports are you using for logging? Does the console transport work? Perhaps the new production server has a network issue that prevents it logging to a remote service such as CouchDB or Loggly.

If you add a simple console.log('...') line next to your winston log lines do those get fired. This will confirm or deny that your winston log lines are getting called on the production server

```
winston.info('winston log test')
console.log('console log test')
```

Comment: i am using filetransport, i am not making use of any remote logging. also console.log works. not only that, i just verified that winston console transport works just fine!! its only the file transport that doesnt work. it logs the very first message and then doesnt log anything else. i am completely clueless as to what is going on. is winston not flushing the logs to the disk?

Comment: Noah, I also found this issue => https://github.com/flatiron/winston/issues/150, I wonder if this is what I am running in to. I am not sure where I would put the workaround code that is included in the last comment in the above link.

Comment: Sounds like winston is not flushing the logs. What version of node are you running? Have you tried using wintson from the git head? npm install -S git://github.com/flatiron/winston.git. Oh I see that the issue is still present in master...Do you need to use the file transport or can you substitue another on in? I have started using Loggly and so far it has been really good

Comment: Noah, here is my code:var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      //TODO: read loglevel from config file
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: "myfile", maxsize : conf.log.maxSize, maxFiles : 10, timestamp: true, prettyPrint : true, level: "info"})
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: conf.log.exception, prettyPrint : true })
    ]
  }); where would the workaround code go? tried a few different things but nothing worked. shld i replace 'log' with 'winston' or 'logger' in my code?

Comment: Can you put that in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)? It is hard to read without formatting

Comment: Noah, here you go: https://gist.github.com/silentuser/5277395. i am not sure where the workaround should go. Also, I just noticed that winston logs the exceptions to the exception log just fine. Its only the 'regular' logging thats affected.

Comment: Noah, please see my answer above. This seems to be a bug/issue with the new version of node. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can can expose the logger instance and have a URL to trigger the required log level. 
I had the same need so I came up with a dynamic log level setter for Winston https://github.com/yannvr/Winston-dynamic-loglevel